# Blender B-bone become huge and blocky

Tags: rigging, armature

First time post here! So when I am doing my rigging and switch view to b-bone
it suddenly become huge and block like the in the image.
[image: B-bone]
Anyone know what's wrong?

It is fine in octahedral though...
[image: Octahedral]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can scale them in edit mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Another way is to use Bendy Bones settings `Display Size X` and `Z`. Then right click Copy to Selected both of them.